# Remote access from Linux to Linux without port forwarding on either side (through a middleman?)

Tags: linux, remote, port-forwarding

I want to remotely access another Linux computer on a different network, but I can't use port forwarding on either network. How would I do that? Is there maybe a website that both the computers can connect to and then it forwards the commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume both PCs are behind NAT and/or SSH ports are closed?

Still TeamViewer must work under Linux. Not sure if it supports Wayland but it absolutely must support X11 based desktop.

Also check [this list](https://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/?license=opensource&platform=linux).

Comment: I used Rustdesk and it worked great. Thank you. Doesn't work for Wayland though.

Comment: Yeah, I liked RustDesk as well.